# jquery grid and javascript best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im new to jquery and need some help.

I have written a table that act like a grid with help from jquery.

When a user click on Name column the user will be redirected to the details page.

Now I want to know if I can do this in a better way?

And should the JS code be in the page or in a separated JS file?

Here is the code.

```
    <table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="name">Namn</th>
            <th data-field="location">Ort</th>
            <th data-field="phone">Telefon</th>
            <th data-field="buildinmonth">Bygga inom</th>
            <th data-field="houselot">Har tomt</th>
            <th data-field="created">Skapad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><span id="open" data-id="@item.Id">@item.Name</span></td>
                <td>@item.Location</td>
                <td>@item.Phone</td>
                <td>@item.BuildInMonth</td>
                <td>@item.HouseLot</td>
                <td>@String.Format("{0:d}", item.CreatedDate)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            scrollable: false,
            sortable: true
        });

    $("#grid #open").click(function () {
        window.location.replace("/lead/details/" + $(this).data("id"));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `javacode`? What is this language you speak of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a user click on Name column the user will be redirected to the details page. Now I want to know if I can do this in a better way?

This seems ok. The only thing I feel can be adde to this is on hover of the Name column, you can show a tooltip of "Show more details" or something more intuitive.

> And should the JS code be in the page or in a separated JS file?

Yes I always prefer to have all my JS code in a seperate file. The advantage of doing so is that you can minify the JS code later on.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, dont need to use any jquery click event, when the html table is loading that time we can give a `<a>` tag like,

```
<td><a href="../lead/details/"+"@item.Id" ><span id="open" data-id="@item.Id">@item.Name</span></a></td>
```